# Can't find output file with Python in Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, pyobjc

I just started learning Python about a week ago. I've made considerable progress thanks to everyone who has asked and answered questions. I came across a problem last night and after a lot of searching and pondering-- I still can't figure it out.

I tried making a Python project in xcode but I can't find the output file. I started the project by selecting "Cocoa-Python Application from the "Choose your template menu:" In the main.py file, I have the following code:

```
import objc
import Foundation
import AppKit
from PyObjCTools import AppHelper

file = open('test.txt', 'w')

print >> file, 'Test of the emergency broadcast system.'
print 'This is merely a test...'

file.close()
```

The console shows the "This is merely a test..." statement but I can't find the output file 'test.txt' anywhere. I've searched the computer and it's nowhere to be found. I'm sure it's something silly, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print this to your console, and you'll see the file name:

```
print file
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

---

If that just shows you the relative path, print the cwd like so:

```
from os import getcwd
print 'Current directory:', getcwd()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.getcwd

Comment: nice, thanks! Your second suggestion provided the answer. I had been using PyCharm before and got used to the output files just appearing in the current directory.